# Correct Go type to pass to C function?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm porting some server code I wrote in C over to Go and it uses an encryption library I *really* don't want to rewrite. Instead I'm trying to use Cgo to write a wrapper so that the rest of my code can call it more easily. Here's part of the header for the lib:

```
// encryption/encryption.h
#define CRYPT_BBCFG  1

typedef struct {
    // ...bunch of fields...
    uint32_t bb_posn; 
} CRYPT_SETUP;

int CRYPT_CreateKeys(CRYPT_SETUP* cs, void* key, unsigned char type);
```

And here's the proof-of-concept snippet I'm trying to get to work:

```
package goserv

//#include "encryption/encryption.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    cdata := new(C.struct_CRYPT_SETUP)
    key := make([]byte, 48)
    C.CRYPT_CreateKeys(cdata, &key, C.CRYPT_BLUEBURST)
}
```

I defined a test function (`int test() { return 1; }`) in the header and have no problem calling that from my code (via `C.test()`) nor referencing any of the #defined'd constants (`C.CRYPT_BBCFG`) but get the following error when I attempt to run *go install goserv*:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CRYPT_CreateKeys", referenced from:
   __cgo_e89359206bf1_Cfunc_CRYPT_CreateKeys in goserv.cgo2.o
       (maybe you meant: __cgo_e89359206bf1_Cfunc_CRYPT_CreateKeys)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

At this point I'm assuming I'm just not calling the function with the correct arguments. I was under the impression that cdata is of type `*C.struct_CRYPT_SETUP`, key should be `*byte` (though it doesn't work without the & either) and C.CRYPT_BLUEBURST of type...something. Trying `C.uchar(CRYPT_BLURBURST)` also doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions on getting this code to compile?

Edit: Forgot my platform, I'm running Mac OS X 10.10

Edit2 (SOLVED): Jsor's point about using unsafe.Pointer with the address of the first element of key helped but I also had to move my C source files into the same directory as my Go file. There was another type error resulting from using C.struct_CRYPT_DATA instead of C.CRYPT_DATA, so if anyone else runs into errors like this:

```
./goserv.go:18: cannot use cdata (type *C.struct_CRYPT_SETUP) as type *C.struct___0 in argument to _Cfunc_CRYPT_CreateKeys
```

Then remove the struct_ prefix (though the cgo docs say that's how to directly reference C struct types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `&key[0]`, otherwise you're pointing to the [Slice Header](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader), which is a struct of 3 values. You end up getting a pointer to a pointer to your buffer, which is probably not what you want.

In general, the pointer to the backing buffer of a slice is `&slice[0]`, not `&slice`.

As a standard disclaimer: be warned about passing Go-allocated buffers into C. Almost everybody does it, (including me) but it [may not be a good idea, and may stop being supported at some point](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8310). It's **probably** fine as long as you keep a reference to the data for the entire duration it's in C, and don't store the pointer for later use on the C side, but it's plausible you'll end up with weirdness due to the Go 1.3 stack moving GC.

Update: Something I just remembered -- `void*` in C is analogous to Go's `unsafe.Pointer`. So your call should be:

```
C.CRYPT_CreateKeys(cdata, unsafe.Pointer(&key[0]), C.CRYPT_BLUEBURST)
```

Another issue may be if you usually link an external library with `-l`. For this, use

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -llibname
```

In the area right above `import "C"` where you do your includes.

Edit2: Also, looking at it more, it looks like the function `CRYPT_CreateKeys` is not defined in the header file -- only the function prototype. Make sure if it's defined in a separate .c file to declare it `extern`. Not doing so **will** trip up Go.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm sure it brings me closer to getting this to work but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @drodman When you compile your C program, do you usually have a `-l` flag? Because you need to do that in Go too. I'll update my answer if that's the case.

Comment: The C code doesn't use anything other than the standard C lib, so I have nothing to specify with the -l flag. I had tried the unsafe.Pointer before but not with the address of the first element of the array, that's a good idea but I can't escape these linker errors. Should be doing something in addition to running go install?

Comment: @drodman -- Also, don't forget to declare all the functions and variables not fully defined in your header file as `extern`.

Comment: It's working, thank you so much! I had to move the C source files into the same directory as my go file (which I need to figure out how to circumvent) as well as take your advice on using unsafe.Pointer for passing the key. Ran into a minor type error as well but I'm editing my question to indicate that

Answer (score 0):

One more point if you are passing buffers in between go
And C. It’s good option to write your C code in a way that, 
It copies buffer locally passed by GO. 
This will help when you are typecasting your buffer to
Int* or some other pointer type.
This way you will be independent of the buffer supplied 
By Cgo.